# Unexpected next() behavior in python, line appears to be skipped

Tags: python

Here's the code I'm running:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    for i,line in enumerate(fin):
        print i
        print fin.next()
```

Where 'test.txt' is:

```
    5
    9 6
    4 6 8
    0 7 1 5
```

The output I am getting is:

```
0 
9 6 

1
0 7 1 5
```

I am confused as to why the '4 6 8' line is being skipped. I expected line 2 to be printed on the first iteration, and line 3 to be printed on the second iteration, and line 4 to be printed on the third iteration.

Instead I am getting line 4 on the second iteration.

Comment: Can you please post your actual code, with the right indentation and the colons? It's very hard to tell whether you wanted `fin.next()` to happen each time through the loop, or once at the end…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you do `for i,line in enumerate(fin)`, the call to `enumerate` is already  calling `fin.next()` under the hood. Therefore, when you call `fin.next` manually later on, you get the next line after the line that you are already processing. This is why you appear to skip lines.

If you want to observe more of this behavior, take a look at the output produced by the following snippet:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print zip(L1, L2)
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

Compare that with the following snippet:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    print zip(fin, fin)
```

Where the output is:

```
[('1 2 3 4\n' , 'a b c d \n')]
```

Do you now see why your output seemed to be skipping lines?

Comment: You should include the output of your examples, people reading this won't always have the possibility to try it out. :)

Comment: @flornquake: Normally, I would, but I'm not at a terminal at the moment. I'd appreciate it if you were and could, though

Comment: @flornquake: I noticed that your suggested edit was rejected. I'm sorry, [I tried](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194722/190564)

Answer (score 3):

`fin.next()` is iterating the `fin` file object, moving the cursor to the next line, so when you get back to the top of the while loop, you've "skipped" the line.  You want to print `line`, not `fin.next()`.